# Splitting principle in equivariant cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, dg.differential-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, sg.symplectic-geometry

The following is a weaker version of what is called splitting principle in
 [Appendix C, page 12](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~karshon/monograph), see also for a lighter version [Brions Eq cohom and eq intersection theory, page 6](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/notes.html):
Let $G$ be a compact (complex) connected Lie group with torus $T\subset G$ and $N$ its normalizer, $W=N/T$ its Weyl group. Let $X$ be any $G$-variety. 
Then, there is an isomorphism

$ H_G^* (X) \cong (H_T^*(X))^W $
of graded algebras. For $X=pt$ this is known to be Chevalley's restriction theorem.

My question is, can one drop the assumption on $G$ and $T$ to be compact? I came across an article  [VarVas, page 12](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.3992), where that has been claimed (with G=Gl_n, X quasi-projective) to be a standard result and no reference is provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The embedding of the unitary group $U_n$ into $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is a homotopy equivalence; this is easily seen to imply that $H^*_{U_n}(X)$ is isomorphic to $H^*_{GL_n}(X)$. So the result for compact groups implies that for $GL_n$.

The same idea works for any reductive complex algebraic group $G$, since the embedding of a maximal compact subgroup into $G$ is a homotopy equivalence.